# docker compose using a specific image complied on another machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image

I am trying to reproduce an error we have on a production machine. I have created a virtual machine with the same versions of Ubuntu and Docker and Docker Compose.

I have built an image using a different version of docker(it won't build using the older versions on the virtual machine and the answers suggest upgrading docker).

I have copied the image to the virtual machine.

How do I run the specific version image as part of the docker compose specification?

Do I need to copy it to a specific location, or can i give it as part of the docker-compose up command?

Comment: If `docker images` already lists the image, you should be able to change the Compose `image:` to match (maybe deleting a `build:` block).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I worked it out.

```
docker import /path/to/app_image
```

before

```
docker-compose up -d app
```

Comment: Do you mean `docker load`?  `load` imports an image and is somewhat common in disconnected environments; `import` tries to reconstruct a container from an exported dump and is pretty unusual.

Comment: I'll have a look at "load", but import worked for what I wanted to do.